# Avoid displaying table sorting arrows under Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I need to display a single-row dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, HTML

stack = [42, 27, 13]
df = pd.DataFrame([stack], columns=[1, 2, 3], index=["stack"])
display(HTML(df.to_html())) # or simply: display(df)
```

[image: HTML output]

Is it possible to get rid of the sorting arrows, which are useless here?

Comment: What version are you using? I'm not able to replicate you result using the same code; I get no arrows. You might have a jupyter extension or so that does that, or somehow you altered the default behavior.

Comment: My bad! Indeed, among my forgotten Jupyter Extensions, there was a checked `table_beautifier`... Thanks a lot. Would you like to transform your comment into an answer?

Comment: You can simply use `df.style`
No need to import display or HTML

Comment: @OsamaNaveed Yes, but in my real code I use it interactively with `ipywidgets`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the discussion we had in the comment. You had a Jupyter extension installed on your system (called `table_beautifier`).

Disabling this should get the expected result (without sorting arrows).